# What does "Failed to provision bridges" mean?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, gae-module

Google search doesn't seem to have heard of this error, but I'm unable to escape it:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Server responded with code [400]:
  Bad Request Unexpected HTTP status 400.
  Failed Project Preparation (app_id='s~rrowland-test-project-2').
  Error "Failed to provision bridges." during VmProvisionBridges.
```

I have followed the instructions at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/nodejs/hello-world exactly. I have tried new projects. I've tried clearing out the VM buckets.

This appears during the deploy process after running

```
gcloud preview app deploy
```

From the sample app's root directory:

```
nodejs-docs-samples/appengine/hello-world
```

Comment: I am also running into this issue while trying to deploy the python hello world application.

Comment: @jqualls I don't know why this happens, but see my answer for a workaround.

Comment: lol Nevermind! It went through build steps for 10 minutes before ultimately giving me the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Launching a permanent VM instance myself fixed this for me.

https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances

Edit: lol! Never mind. It built for 10 minutes and then ultimately ended in the same error.

Comment: What region did you put it in. I tried provisioning one and its still throwing the same exception.

Comment: I think I may have resolved the issue. I got it working by following the steps listed in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working. I think there may be a bad state in the project. Here are the steps I went through to get it working.

1. create a new project
2. enable billing for that project
3. LEAVE CLOUD CONSOLE (if you attempt to navigate around it starts enabling API's I.E Compute Engine)
4. Go to command line and run `gcloud init`
5. create a new config for your new project
6. when it asks if you want to use repositories say no
7. attempt to deploy the application `gcloud preview app deploy`
8. this may result in a timeout and a message saying try again `try again`
9. if all went well it will say it is enabling the remote build service
10. the app might take some time to build the docker image but it should deploy at this point

[image]

Hopefully, this will help someone else get past this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the write-up. I just re-ran `gcloud preview app deploy` before trying your steps to make sure it wasn't a temporary service issue. It actually succeeded, so I do think it may have been an issue on their end that is now cleared up.